# Building a confirmation gateway function

Tags: javascript, angular

Let's assume I have several operations in my app that require a confirmation by the user.
E.g. I have several buttons that change or delete things in a database.
The functions `deleteEntry(id)` and `changeEntry(id, oldvalue, newvalue)` delete and change data accordingly.

A user calls those functions by clicking links:

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="deleteEntry(id)">Delete Entry</a>`

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="changeEntry(id, oldvalue, newvalue)">Change Entry</a>`

What's the most efficient way to always ask for confirmation before the actual function is called?
Is there any way to pass function with values to another function?

What would be the best way to build the expected behaviour without hardcoding functionality into the `confirmAction` function?

In very broad and unrealistic pseudocode I'd like something like this:

```
function confirmAction(function_to_be_executed(params)) {
  showConfirmationAndAbortButton();
  if(confirmed){
    function_to_be_executed();
  } else {
     alert("Aborted.")
  }
}
```

Where `showConfirmationAndAbortButton();` shows buttons to set `confirmed` either `true` or `false` and `function_to_be_executed(params)` could equal deleteEntry(id)